# Link android app to Google Game Services?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

This might sound like a stupid question but I can't grasp if I'm doing this correctly.

I created an app in the developer console using the "Game Services"-tab. Meaning I didn't actually "create" an app as far as I understand. In the "All applications"-tab I have ZERO apps because I haven't created one there yet. But if I check the "Linked apps"-tab, I already have an app there with a bundle-id xxx.yyy.zz (not the real id). If I now create an app in the "All applications"-tab with the same bundle-id (xxx.yyy.zz), will it automatically be linked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To properly link an app to the Game Service you will need to also specify the fingerprint of the signing certificate you use for your app and the package must match.

Check out **Step 2** in [this](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart) guide for the exact steps needed.

Comment: Thank you! I came to this conclusion by trial and error, but forgot to answer my own question. I knew of the fingerprint etc. since I followed the guide, but it wasn't clear on _when_ the app actually is counted as "connected". So in other words, all that is needed seem to be that the app's package name matches the one on Game Services (and ofc also all the other steps in the guide).